# Building a poly-time verifier given a poly-time decider

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomial-time

Can I build a polynomial time verifier for problem, given a non-deterministic polynomial time decider for that problem?

I assume I should modify the decider such that it will verify the certificate. 
Can I use the given decider as is (without any modification)?

Comment: Yes, if the problem is in P then any (empty) certificate will do, as you can check the solution in polynomial time by reconstructing it.

Comment: @AlbertHendriks Make a full-fledged answer?

Comment: @AlbertHendriks The problem is not necessarily in P.

Comment: I see. I think it depends on the context. Any P verifier automatically leads to an NP decider and vice versa, but there are syntactic/semantic differences. The input to the verifier is the same as the certificate for the decider, but "certificate" is not equivalent to "input"